# c++ openssl 1.1.0l: supporting different self signed certificates with a single x509 store

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, x509

first i need to mention that i am new to openssl.

i encountered the following behavior in a server application i am testing.
in the server:

1. create a x509 cert store.
2. add 2 different self signed certificates.
3. connect 2 different clients, each with one of the self signed certificates.

the result:
until the client whose certificate was added last to the certificate store connects and is verified, the 2nd client verification fails.

is there a configuration to prevent this ordering? that any client with a certificate from the certificates store will be verified regardless of connection order?

adding some simplified code to clarify:

```
SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());  
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, nullptr);  

X509 * cert1 = PEM_read_X509(certFile1, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);  
X509 * cert2 = PEM_read_X509(certFile2, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);  
X509_STORE * certStore = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(ctx);  

X509_STORE_add_cert(certStore, cert1);  
X509_STORE_add_cert(certStore, cert2);
```

Comment: What does "add 2 self signed certificates means"? The complexity of openssl means that you could be referring to many different things, so at most that can be said here are random guesses. Unfortunately, the complexity of openssl means that even a short code sample here would be too large for stackoverflow.com. I suggest that you try openssl's mailing lists.

Comment: So.. you're running verify-host and the client doesn't agree with the cert the site is serving up. A site won't serve more than one "this is me" certificate. I submit that your need for multiple certs is unfounded. IF your trying to do this from two different domains that's not how its done. You use one cert with one domain in the Subject, and *both* domains in the SAN list. That cert should be signed by an entity the client trusts (ideally signed by the CA). Further, the clients should only have the CA public cert. If they have the full signing cert you're definitely doing this wrong.

Comment: Or... your using client-certs to be verified by the server, and each is derived from a completely different CA. If that's the case, no, I know of now way to have a client-verify "choose" an auth-verify cert. Frankly, I'm surprised you can use a bundle with more than one at all. Its the same concept but in reverse.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now that I was going at it from the wrong way.

Comment: although my knowledge of OpenSSL is very shallow, I think the question has merit ... doesn't it relate to how to implement a server to accept SNI handshakes ?